# Java iterator get next without incrementing

Tags: java

I am writing the following loop in Java, for each loop I want to access the current and the next element of linked list r:

```
    List<T> r = new LinkedList();

    for (int i=0; i < r.size() - 1; i++) {
        T current = r.get(i);
        T next = r.get(i+1);
    }
```

This might be wasting as everytime I call get(i), it start from the beginning so the run time order of the code is O(n^2). How do I achieve the same using Iterator (this time it will be O(n))? This is my first attempt:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    T current = it;
    T next = it.next();
}
```

Comment: Which List implementation are you using? I assume LinkedList because ArrayList has O(1) for get...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maintain a variable `previous` that is equal to the previous loop's `current` value.

```
T previous = null;
// If it makes sense to skip the first "null, first element" pair...
if (it.hasNext())
{
    previous = it.next();
}    

while (it.hasNext())
{
    T current = it.next();
    // Process previous and current here.

    // End of loop, after processing.  Maintain previous reference.
    previous = current;
}
```

This will be O(n) because you are using the `Iterator` over your entire linked list.

Comment: Great! So it.next() automatically move the iterator to the next one?

Comment: @clcto On the first iteration, there is no `previous`, so I initialized it to `null`.  If it doesn't make sense to process a "null, first element" pair, then you can initialize it by adding `if(it.hasNext()) previous = it.next();`, so that the `while` loop will only process actual pairs from the list.

Comment: @DzungNguyen Yes, each call to `next()` always returns the next item, unless there are no more items, in which case it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 4):

In each iteration, you should keep around a variable that will be the "current" and one that will be the "next". And you start processing your information starting from the *second* iteration, when you already have a `current` saved from the previous round.

```
T current = null;
T next = null;
Iterator<T> iter = r.iterator();

while ( iter.hasNext() ) {

    next = iter.next();
    if ( current != null ) { // Passed the first iteration

        // Now you can use current and next, they both have values.

    }
    current = next; // Save what was the "next" as the next "current".
}
```

It's best to make sure that the list itself doesn't have null values. If it does, and it's a valid value, then you should have a boolean flag instead of just checking whether `current != null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
T current = r.get(0);
for ( int i=0; i < r.size()-1; i++ ) {
   T next = r.get(i+1);
     // do stuiff here
   current = next;
}
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to use ArrayQueue if you don't mind the space complexity

```java
      var queue = new ArrayDeque<>(list);
      while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        var first = reversed ? queue.pollLast() : queue.pollFirst();
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
          var second = reversed ? queue.getLast() : queue.getFirst();
          //your code goes here
        }
      }
//or
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        var first = reversed ? queue.removeLast() : queue.removeFirst();
        var second = reversed ? queue.peekLast() : queue.peekFirst();
        if (second!=null) {
          //your code goes here
        }
      }
```