# Getting the current and the next element from a collection in a loop, using Iterator, in Java

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have a `Collection<T>`, named "col". Not important what contains the class T. When I iterate the collection, at each iteration I need to have the current element and the next.

```
Iterator it = col.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  T line = (T) it.next();
  T nextLine = it.hasNext()? NEXT_LINE : null;
  // more Java code with line and nextLine
}
```

"NEXT_LINE" is not a declared constant, but an invalid code. I need to replace it with a valid Java code that returns the next element from the collection, without incrementing again the iterator.

I found this link:
[Java iterator get next without incrementing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080272/java-iterator-get-next-without-incrementing)

The weakness of this solution, in my case, is if the collection contains only 1 element, I have to do too many changes in my code. If there is a solution for my version, the case with 1 element is covered, because nextLine is null.

I can also convert the collection in an ArrayList, but I'll do this only when I consider there is not a better way:

```
ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(col);
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
  T line = list.get(i);
  T nextLine = i<list.size()-1 ? list.get(i+1) : null;
  // more Java code with line and nextLine
}
```

Comment: linkedlist sounds more suitable here

Answer (score 3):

Guava contains the [`PeekingIterator`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/23.0/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html) interface, which could be your solution.

```
PeekingIterator it = Iterators.peekingIterator(col.iterator());
while (it.hasNext()) {
    T line = (T) it.next();
    T nextLine = it.hasNext()? it.peek() : null;
}
```

More information [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained#peekingiterator). Seems to match your current structure well.

Answer (score 2):

The usage for Iterator is as follows (1 `it.hasNext()` and 1 `it.next()`).

```
Iterator<T> it = col.iterator();
T previous = null;
if (it.hasNext()) {
    previous = it.next();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      T next = it.next();
      // ... previous ... next ..
      previous = next;
    }
}
```